# PHP, shell_exec. How to run a command with several inputs

Tags: php, shell, debian

I'm trying to access the manual of using the command man (debian).

Using this code:

```
$out = shell_exec("man");
echo $out;
```

the output is:

```
What manual page do you want?
```

How can I select a page from php code?

Answer (score 2):

`man` by itself doesn't do anything. You have to tell it which command you want to see the manual for. For example: `man cd` will show you the man page for the `cd` command.

For example try: `echo "<pre>" . shell_exec("man cd");`